# Set the scrollable height of an entire page regardless of content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way using css and html to control the maximum scrollable height of a page, regardless of the content which is present on the page?

For a concrete, hypothetical example: say the `<body>` is incredibly simple - a `<div>` which is 5000px tall.  How would you set the scrollable height to be only 2000px?

Thus it would appear that the 2000th pixel is the last pixel on the page.  The browser's scroll bar would appear to be at the bottom, not just "stuck" halfway down the page.  Am I missing something simple to achieve this behavior? I would prefer pure css/html because it seems like it should be doable, but I would accept js.

Comment: Put the big div inside a smaller div (with max-height and perhaps min-height too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like [***this***](http://jsfiddle.net/pEWy6/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
     <!--your content here-->
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
    height:2000px;
    overflow:auto;
}
.inner {
    height:5000px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: This is much closer, but for some reason it is just cutting the contents of the page where I set the limit, instead of limiting the scrolling.  So I can still scroll the full length of the page, but nothing appears below the height of `.inner`  How strange...

Comment: It seems that an absolutely positioned div INSIDE of the `body` (which is positioned lower than the `body`) causes the scroll to go to the bottom of IT instead of the bottom of body.  But if an absolutely positioned element is outside of the flow, why isn't it just hidden by overflow:hidden, since it is a child of `<body>`?

Comment: Edited your fiddle to include what I'm talking about.  Weirdly enough, in the fiddle, only the fiddle window gets the scroll bars, not the container.  But in my production site since the "container" is the body the result is the whole page gets the scroll bars. http://jsfiddle.net/9SPDq/2/

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what you need. Can you provide an illustration perhaps?

Comment: What I was trying to solve was outside the scope of this question.  This got me on the right track and is a simple, correct explanation, so I've accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the body height to a specific number and set overflow to hidden.

```
body{
  height:2000px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Made an [example here](http://jsbin.com/qudihemu)

Comment: When I set overflow:hidden on my body element, no scroll bars appear at all?

Comment: Make sure the body height is greater than your window height. Remember, scroll bars only appear when the content is larger than the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

Use `max-height` or `height` css properties and `overflow:hidden` on your container element.  It will hide everything that is greater than the height you specify, therefore limiting the scrollbar height.

I should also mention that you can use `overflow-y:hidden` will achieve the same thing, but will only affect top and bottom edges of an element. See more details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp).